# Why is my account banned?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

Why has my account been banned?  I wanted to answer this guy's question and help other people out.  If my account has been banned it is because I asked one stupid question once.  I usually try to contribute as best as I can and I am a programmer with 15 years of experience.  I am not just some noob who does not know what he is doing.

Comment: This is [this Adam Freeman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/538458/adam-freeman)

Comment: Did it ever occur to you to click on the link given in the message that you get when you try to create an answer?

Answer (score 16):

It appears your account is banned from answering questions because you have four deleted answers, out of six answers. They were deleted for various reasons, including a rant ("apple sucks"), and three answers that were comments or their own question.

There is really nothing we can do to unban you since it's a system imposed ban. I would suggest that you read the link provided and keep in mind what Stack Overflow is for ( hint: it's not for ranting about Apple)

The only way I could have see that this could have been improved for you is if we as moderators had commented and said, "Hey, don't have an answer which [consists entirely of a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5254272/16587)":

> Can someone please explain this post?

Or, not to have [answers that are really questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277687/how-do-i-set-the-active-sdk-in-xcode-using-applescript/5185044#5185044):

> I have tried something like this for the device but I cannot get it to work. XCode tries to launch the application but then the app exits with a status of 5?

Unfortunately, we didn't do that.  The Stack Overflow Q&A system takes a little getting used to. In this case, it appears you thought this was a forum for free-range discussion, it is not.  We could have improved on our side by commenting before deleting (but it still would have been deleted), that way you (hopefully) would not do that behavior again.

That is its own problem, since we'd rather not have to comment on every single thing we delete (as that would mean I would have hundreds of comments just revolving around deleted posts).  All I can say is, try to follow the directions outlined in the link, and I hope you're unbanned and able to contribute soon.

Comment on this post if you'd like for me to link to your deleted answers so you can edit them and have them undeleted. If you edit them to be actual answers, then I'd be happy to undelete them.

I've cleared the spam flags from your 'apple sucks' rant, and re-deleted that answer. If that contributed to your system ban then maybe it may be enough to get you out of it. Can't promise anything though, since I don't know the exact algorithm behind banning users for bad content.